# Excel alternative to Unique without VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create UNIQUE alternative for Excel 2019 as It only works in Office 365, but I don't know where to start.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ";1;UNIQUE(IF($B$1:$B$100=A2;$C$1:$C$100;"")))
```

https://dollarexcel.com/how-to-get-unique-values-without-unique-function/

I've been trying to use this one, but I don't know where should I put the MATCH function in the IF or in place of UNIQUE.

Comment: you have TEXTJOIN but not UNIQUE?  I ask because there is only one version that is that way and that is Excel 2019.  I want to make sure the only issue is the UNIQUE.

Comment: Yes, the only issue is UNIQUE. It works like I want it to in Office 365, but I have a problem with it in Excel 2019.

Answer (score 2):

If `TEXTJOIN()` is to be used you could create a valid xml-string and use appropriate xpath-syntax to return an array of unique elements through `FILTERXML()`:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,IF(B1:B6=A2,C1:C6,""))&"</s></t>","//s[not(preceding::*=.)]"))
```

Though non-volatile, there could be some tweaks you may have to make due to the fact xml-input is for example case-sensitive ('A' != 'a') and some characters are harder to process; for more information on that I'd like to redirect you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837697/9758194) post where you can read about that in the bottom-alinea.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use OFFSET which makes it Volatile:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF((COUNTIFS(OFFSET(C1,,,ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,COUNTA(C:C)))),C1:C22,OFFSET(B1,,,ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,COUNTA(C:C)))),A2)=1)*(B1:B22=A2),C1:C22,""))
```

as per your local settings you will need to use `;` in place of all my `,`

[image]

Comment: The only drawback to that would be if the data creates a string too large for concat, which I think has a 255 character limit.

Comment: I would put that as an answer. It would be a good alternative if the strings are short enough.